# Need replace html string text from react component

Tags: reactjs, react-static

Issue : -
we are facing the shortcode issue. we use shortcode {{email}} for email subscription in content and the server provides content as HTML string on the frontend side. we render string to HTML on the frontend side from dengerouslySetInnerHTML react function..

Example : -
`let description = '<p>contect here {{email}} content here {{email}} content here</p>';`

we use react dengerouslySetInnerHTML function that convert HTML string to  actual HTML.
`<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: description }} ></div>`

I'm doing -
replacing {{email}} text from react email component but we are not able to insert react component in the string.

Like -  `description.replace('{{email}}', <EmailComponent />)`

Answer (score 1):

i think you can convert `<EmailComponent />` to string

```
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server'

console.log(description.replace('{{email}}', renderToString(<EmailComponent />)))
```

Comment: import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server' its not work in  react-static

Comment: This is awesome and resolved the issue. Thanks a lot.